# Trigger click only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a quiz plugin, where answer is submitted once "next" button is clicked. I want it to be triggered once the answer is clicked. I've managed to trigger a click, but it clicks through all the questions. How do i make it clicked only once?

My code

```
$(".wpProQuiz_questionListItem").each(function(){
   $(this).find("label").click(function(event){
      $(this).find(".wpProQuiz_questionInput").prop('checked', true);
      $(this).parents().find(".wpProQuiz_button").click();
   });
});
```

html

```
<ol class="wpProQuiz_list">
   <li class="wpProQuiz_listItem">
      <ul class="wpProQuiz_questionList">
         <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem"> <!-- that's the answer -->
            <label>
                <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_1_1" value="1"> <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/08/76/63/bahia-de-caraquez.jpg" class="questionimage">                                   
            </label>
            <input name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;" type="button">
         </li>
      </ul>
      <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;">
   </li>
   <li class="wpProQuiz_listItem">Same code goes here</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: that's a code from wordpress plugin.

Comment: @deltree, you're incorrect. Nesting an `<input>` within a `<label>` is a valid way of indicating the labeled control ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-label-element)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching for the button inside of all parents, including the element `<ol class="wpProQuiz_list">`, which returns all buttons in the list. So you must define the parent, for which to find the button.

So long story short - here is the fix:

```
$(this).parents(".wpProQuiz_questionListItem").find(".wpProQuiz_button").click();
```

And a working snippet

```js
$(".wpProQuiz_questionListItem").each(function(){
   $(this).find("label").click(function(event){
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
      $(this).find(".wpProQuiz_questionInput").prop('checked', true);
      $(this).parents(".wpProQuiz_questionListItem").find(".wpProQuiz_button").click();
     event.preventDefault();
   })
});

$(".wpProQuiz_button").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="wpProQuiz_list">
   <li class="wpProQuiz_listItem">
      <ul class="wpProQuiz_questionList">
         <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem"> <!-- that's the answer -->
            <label id="one">
                <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_1_1" value="1"> <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/08/76/63/bahia-de-caraquez.jpg" class="questionimage">                                   
            </label>
            <input id="btn-one" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;" type="button" />

         </li>
      </ul>
      <input id="btn-one-outer" type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;">
   </li>
   <li class="wpProQuiz_listItem">
      <ul class="wpProQuiz_questionList">
         <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem"> <!-- that's the answer -->
            <label id="two">
                <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_1_1" value="2"> <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/08/76/63/bahia-de-caraquez.jpg" class="questionimage">                                   
            </label>
            <input id="btn-two" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;" type="button" />
         </li>
      </ul>
      <input id="btn-two-outer" type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;">
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did you try the snippet? Only `btn-one` is clicked if you select option `one`, and same goes for option `two`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: sorry. it was for a moment. now it's not

Comment: There's another button which you didn't include in your question. This solution now should work.

Comment: yeah. I'm  experimenting with hacks. It only works, though, if you click on the next button. I'm trying to make it work on label click

Comment: Look at the snippet - it works on label click. I don't know if you noticed, but I changed my answer, the class inside the jQuery selector should be `.wpProQuiz_questionListItem`.

Answer (score 1):

i think `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` will help you

example for your code:

```
$(".wpProQuiz_questionListItem").each(function(){
   $(this).find("label").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();   
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $(this).find(".wpProQuiz_questionInput").prop('checked', true);
      $(this).parents().find(".wpProQuiz_button").trigger('click');
   });
});
```